# Why pressing F to join two vertices not work?

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices

I press F to merge two vertices, but they only extend a bit (second photo below), not join together? Could you please help me out of this problem?
[image: These are vertices I want to merge]
[image: After pressing F, not join together]
[Link to my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K69nN8fdZZZHNHr3qKuxlrAbmkH19Dka/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Moonboots already pointed the issue, so just extension - after you delete duplicated vertices you can connect ends of path also by Alt+C (Toggle Cyclic - Close/Open Loop) without need to select points. Also in this case if you would use this operator the issue will appear by it self :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if I grab your top vertex and move it to the right...

[image]

here is what I have, which means you had some vertices overlapping:

[image]

In a bezier curve, a vertex can't be connected to more than 2 other vertices, so just delete these vertices and join again with <kbd>F</kbd>, or as pointed out by  vklidu, select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.